# How do you make a shake animation for a button using Swift 3

Tags: ios, animation, swift3, uibutton, xcode8

I have a function that gets called every 3 seconds. How can I make a shaking animation for the *button* that shakes side to side.

```
func shakeButton() {
    if opened == false {
        //Shake Animation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

if I understood you correctly, try this on shake animation.
Simply use this method in your UIButton subclass

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    func shake() {
        let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation.x")
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
        animation.duration = 0.6
        animation.values = [-20.0, 20.0, -20.0, 20.0, -10.0, 10.0, -5.0, 5.0, 0.0 ]
        layer.add(animation, forKey: "shake")
    }
}
```

Then you create `CustomButton` somewhere in code or storyboard/xib and call `myButton.shake()`

You can simply adopt this solution on your needs

UPD: I have edit example than exactly fitted your needs

UPD2: another one solution
Just create `UIButton` extension

```
extension UIButton {

    func shake() {
        let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation.x")
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
        animation.duration = 0.6
        animation.values = [-20.0, 20.0, -20.0, 20.0, -10.0, 10.0, -5.0, 5.0, 0.0 ]
        layer.add(animation, forKey: "shake")
    }

}
```

ans use on you button action callback:

```
@IBAction func shake(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.shake()
}
```

Comment: I created the subclass and added the code above, now how do I call the `mybutton.shake()` properly. In my viewcontroller, I added `giftButton.shake()`, but it said UIButton has no member shake.

Comment: seems to me you use outlet from storyboard and it is UIButton class.

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to know what you're looking for here, without a sample GIF or something. But if it's what I think it is, where a button moves from an initial center, to a new center slightly to a left, to a new center slightly to the right, and maybe another time or two before centering again you should look at UIView's animateKeyframes(withDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:) method.